# Troubles unpacking list of lists using for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have several columns, each with list of lists and values inside the nested list.

I have been unsuccessfully trying to unpack the lists into separate columns. Since each column has 3 lists inside another list, I am trying to unpack the three lists into three separate columns for each column I unpack.

I have tried, creating a list of column names to house the unpacked lists and a list of column names I would like to unpack (scorecard_var)

```
from tqdm import tqdm
def judge_scores(col_name):
    return merged[col_name].apply(pd.Series)
#creating a list to house unpacked columns
col_names =list(chain.from_iterable(('first'+str(i),'second'+str(i),'third'+str(i)) for i in range(1,85))) 
#iterate through list of columns to unpack, unpack and house in col_names columns
for i in tqdm(scorecard_var):
    for x,y,z in zip(*[iter(col_names)]*3):
        merged[[x,y,z]] = judge_scores(i)
```

This gives an error message:

> ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

The list of keys should match the columns as far as I know

I attached a link to the sample of my data
[data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14-Q54jBuVJRQYK4722fhoNRQEv5sRw76)

Its a lot of data (over 1000 columns per row) so I think it makes more sense attaching a link to a sample as opposed to adding it to my question

Here is another sample of my data:

```
{'JudgeID1': {0: ['[]', '[]', '[]'], 3: []},
 'JudgeID2': {0: ['[]', '[]', '[]'], 3: ['[]', '[]', '[]']},
 'JudgeID3': {0: ['[]', '[]', '[]'], 3: []},
 'JudgeID4': {0: ['[]', '[]', '[]'], 3: []},
 'JudgeID5': {0: ['[40 36]', '[40 36]', '[39 37]'], 3: ['[]', '[]', '[]']},
 'JudgeID6': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID7': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID8': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID9': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID10': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID11': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID12': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID13': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID14': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID15': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID16': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID17': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID18': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID19': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID20': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID21': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID22': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID23': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID24': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID25': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID26': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID27': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID28': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID29': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID30': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID31': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID32': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID33': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID34': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID35': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID36': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID37': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID38': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID39': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID40': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID41': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID42': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID43': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID44': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID45': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID46': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID47': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID48': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID49': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID50': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID51': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID52': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID53': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID54': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID55': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID56': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID57': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID58': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID59': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID60': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID61': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID62': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID63': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID64': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID65': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID66': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID67': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID68': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID69': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID70': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID71': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID72': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID73': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID74': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID75': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID76': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID77': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID78': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID79': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID80': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID81': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID82': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID83': {0: nan, 3: nan},
 'JudgeID84': {0: nan, 3: nan}}
```

Comment: you could create some sample data. Most ppl wont search in that linked data for the specific column which causes your problem and try to reproduce the error. create a minimal copy and pasteable example

Comment: @luigigi added a sample of my data

Comment: @Emm And in what variable does this data exist?

Comment: @Aryerez scorecard_var is a list of all the column names in my sample